# How append child to JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Why it's not working like that?

```
let elem = <div></div>
elem.appendChild(<h1>abc</h1>)
```

how I can add child to jsx element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses a virtual dom node, but appendChild can only work with real dom node.

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. Use a real dom node instead of a react node.

```js
const ch = document.createElement("h1");
ch.innerHTML = "abc";
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(ch);
...
return <div id="parent"></div>;
```

2. Use createRoot of "react-dom/client"

```js
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
...
createRoot(document.getElementById("parent")).render(<h1>abc</h1>);
...
return <div id="parent"></div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `appendChild` in JSX. You would directly add the element in:

```
let elem = (
  <div>
    <h1>abc</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Or, you can use different components:

```
import React from 'react';

// Child component
const ChildComponent = () => {
  return <h1>abc</h1>;
};

// Parent component
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to dynamically create a tree of jsx elements from another format

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve?